# Building and populating gui grids in C++

Tags: c++, grid, sudoku

Working with GUIs.

I appreciate that a lot of people ask after how to get started with Windows GUIs. I've written a C++ sudoku solver as a command line piece of code (happy to share if anyone would like).

Could I ask for some guidance on setting up and populating grids with numbers in a gui window?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Qt:
http://qt-project.org/,

it is powerful and easy to use framework that allows efficiently create and maintain gui applications. You can create ui for display/user interaction using Qt, and integrate your command line solver with it...